# ZK AddThis Attributes in Java not in ZUL

Tags: java, zk, zul

I want to implement the AddThis Toolbox

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
  <attribute ca:name="addthis:url">http://www.foobar.org </attribute>
  <attribute ca:name="addthis:title">An excellent website</attribute>      
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
</div>
```

Into something like this, here is my code, I only get the Title of my Homepage into the Twitter box. It works in general but the attributes are not integrated !

```
Div oDivAddThis = new Div();
oDivAddThis.setClass("addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_style");
oDivAddThis.setAttribute("ca:name='addthis:url'", "https://www.test.org");
oDivAddThis.setAttribute("ca:name='addthis:title'",oSearchDAO.getTitle()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription1()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription2());
oDivAddThis.setAttribute("addthis:url", "https://test.org.com/?cp="+oSearchDAO.getImage().trim());
oDivAddThis.setAttribute("addthis:title",oSearchDAO.getTitle()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription1()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription2());

A compGooglePlus = new A();
compGooglePlus.setClass("addthis_button_google_plusone_share");
compGooglePlus.setAttribute("addthis:url", "https://test.org.com/?cp="+oSearchDAO.getImage().trim());
compGooglePlus.setAttribute("addthis:title",oSearchDAO.getTitle()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription1()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription2());

A compFacebook = new A();
compFacebook.setClass("addthis_button_facebook");

A compTwitter = new A();
compTwitter.setClass("addthis_button_twitter");
compTwitter.setAttribute("addthis:url", "https://test.org.com/?cp="+oSearchDAO.getImage().trim());
compTwitter.setAttribute("addthis:title",oSearchDAO.getTitle()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription1()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription2());

A compCompact = new A();
compCompact.setClass("addthis_button_compact");
compGooglePlus.setParent(oDivAddThis);
compFacebook.setParent(oDivAddThis);
compTwitter.setParent(oDivAddThis);
compCompact.setParent(oDivAddThis);
```

I even tried something like this (Client/Attribute Namespace)

```
oDivAddThis.setAttribute("ca:name='addthis:url'", "https://test.org/?cp="+oSearchDAO.getImage().trim());
oDivAddThis.setAttribute("ca:name='addthis:title'",oSearchDAO.getTitle()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription1()+" \n "+oSearchDAO.getDescription2());
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

**UPDATE [SOLVED]**

with the help from Tony (Author of http://zkfiddle.org) I got it working.
My Mistake was that I used setAttibute which is clearly evaluated on server-side.

All I had to do was using setWidgetAttibute which will be evaluated on Client side
and THATS it. :-) Amazing. Thanks to you victor for posting your Ideas and a special thanks
to Tony who helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that NONE of the attributes are not set in this component? If so, You may want to try  tag in the zul page, maybe this can work...

Update: This is what i do when i want to place a URL image, i save the name of the image in my object and acces it in the following way: (using @Listen onCreate event)

```
<treecell>
<!-- STATUS -->
<image src="/Librerias/Imagenes/${each.data.status}.png">
<custom-attributes attributeName="value" />
</image>
</treecell>
```

Comment: Not sure that will work. I get a URL from the DB which represents a Image and for each Image I want to show the AddThis Box. What would be your starting point ?

Comment: I have do the same when using templates to render a tree or a listbox, here is an example of how i set the image name, see the update in the post

Comment: I thing I found the reason why it is not updating the toolbox. I had to add the addthis_toolbox with a Javascript call afterMount in ZK. But still the Attributes do not work and it only shows the Page Title in the Twitterbox. I tried to add a Attribute Object to my Div´s and A´s but the Class Attribute is a little bit tricky to use. The setParent method receives a Item from the IDOM tree and not a Component. Any idea how I can use this class so I can add the namespace etc. ?

Comment: the thing is that I have all the components created in Java. I do no have any ZUL as you can see in my question I do not know how to make this work in Java
<attribute ca:name="addthis:url">http://www.zkoss.org </attribute>

Comment: Solved the problem. I made a Update in my original POST